# Надо ли объединять двойной ключ ради эффективности?

Tags: mysql, инспекция-кода

Есть табличка, в которой primary key - это пара 32-битных ключей `id1`, `id2`.
Соответственно, все ссылки по foreign key на эту таблицу тоже идут по этой паре.

С точки зрения исходной модели у каждого ключа свой смысл, и хранить их парой конечно же удобней с точки зрения читабельности.

Однако интересует - какова эффективность такого решения по сравнению с тем, чтобы объединить эту пару в единый 64-х битный ключ.

Ключи эти всегда идут парой, поэтому так сделать можно.

Вопрос: даст ли это хоть какую-то выгоду с точки зрения любого аспекта производительности, или это будет тоже самое?

Comment: На мой взгляд это вопрос опросник. Я понимаю, что вопрос может быть интересен, но он не содержит однозначно верного ответа и здесь будет холивар. На мой, субъективный, взгляд делить 64 битный ключ на два 32 битных, при условии, что раздельно эти ключи не используются ни при каких обстоятельствах в современных условиях уже не имеет какого-либо большого смысла.

Comment: Я поясню: два 32-битных ключа появились из бизнес модели.

Но при этом в базе они всегда живут парой. То есть вопрос не про разделение 64-х битного ключа на два. А стоит ли ради эффективности пожертвовать наглядностью и два ключа объединить в один.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похожий вопрос поднимался на англоязычном SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460465/composite-primary-key-performance-drawback-in-mysql

Если вы используете InnoDB, то разницы в производительности PK (INT) и (INT, INT) практически нет. Если еще и сами поля происходят из бизнес-модели, то видимо лучше ничего не менять.